# Transform skew without changing element position

Tags: html, css, position, css-transforms, skew

I have created the following markup (an example to demonstrate) with a CSS skew transform:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the inner div `.inner` is being position outside of the container `.wrapper` even though I set `right` to 0 because the inner div is skewed 30 degrees. How can I position the inner div with the right most part being at the same position? I could hard code the value of right, but it would appear differently with different screen sizes. If I set the overflow of the outer div to hidden, the right side would still be misaligned. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996111/how-can-i-keep-my-css-transform-rotate-skew-origin-from-moving-a-few-pixels) which suggests using `transform-origin` and `-webkit-transform-origin`, which I set to `right`, but none of the solutions worked. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `transform-origin: bottom`

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked. I'm just wondering, how come `transform-origin` didn't work when I put in `right` instead of `bottom`? How will I be able to choose the correct one?

Comment: @code you need to get familiar with how transformations works. Here is a detailed answers if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52093362/8620333